# how to get count of using model relation in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, one-to-one

I have 2 models 1 is Job Model which is something like this

```
class Job(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False,blank=False)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=5000,null=True,blank=True)
    slug=AutoSlugField(populate_from='name',null=True, blank=True)
    industry=models.ForeignKey('Industry',null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

and other model is Industry model. This model has one to one relation with Job model
Industry model is like this

```
class Industry(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=2000,null=True, blank=True)
```

Now what i'm trying to do is to get count of jobs against each indsutry using industry model like this

```
{% for industry in industry_2 %}
                      <li><a href="#"><h6 class="category-title">{{ industry.name }}</h6> <span class="category-count">{{ industry.jobs_count }}</span> </a></li>
                      {% endfor %}
```

but its not working for me, please help me in this regard to solve this issue. Do suggest any better method also, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
{% for industry in industry_2 %}
    <li><a href="#"><h6 class="category-title">{{ industry.name }}</h6> <span class="category-count">{{ industry.job_set.count }}</span> </a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Please, note that by default, i.e. if you do not use `related_name` on a `ForeignKey`, the related name is lowercased model name suffixed with `_set`, which makes sense, it's a job set of an industry.

Comment: it worked for me, Thanks